# How to send files to Laravel controller as Normal File elementby using FilePond?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-plugins, filepond

I want to send file to Laravel Controller along with other form fields data, but I am using FilePond.js which sends file as an Async request.

I used FilePondPluginFileEncode plugin and I got file's data as Json object, But I am unable to store data because I didn't find any temp/location of the file.

```
  $file = $request->input('file');
  $name = json_decode($file[0])->name;
  $data = substr($file[0], strpos($file[0], ',') + 1);
  $data = base64_decode($data);
  $storage = Storage::disk('local')->put($name, $data);
```

It stores empty files (with correct name and format)

I want to get file with in Laravel's Controller

Comment: i guess you will have to `base64_decode` the data from that JSON object and write to a file with that content

Comment: @lagbox I've tried this code but it returns **null** ........      
       $file = $request->input('file');
        $data = base64_decode($file[0]);
        dd(json_decode($data, true));

Comment: because you need to decode a specific field from the JSON object named `data` ... the documentation for [the file encode plugin](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-encode/)

Comment: It didn't worked

Comment: what "didn't work"? ... you have to paste up some code of what you are doing (edit your original question and add what you have tried)

Comment: `       data = substr($file[0], strpos($file[0], ',') + 1);
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        $storage = Storage::disk('local')->put($name, $data);`


It stores files but files does not contain any type of data It is an empty file

Comment: and now you are not showing what `$file` even is ... you need to include all the code so people know what you are doing ... you need to decode the JSON, then base64 decode the 'data' property of the object ... good luck

Comment: @lagbox please see the question's detail I'e updated it